# Template Stack and LIFO C++

Tags: c++, templates, stack

So I'm trying to learn about Templates and the Fifo and Lifo stack stuff. I've been playing around with some code that deals with this, and I can get the int data to do what I want for testing but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get this to work with a string. 
The way I have the code keeps crashing on me, but doesn't give me any errors, so I thought I'd pop in here and see if anybody could tell me what I'm doing wrong. Here's my code:

```
-----------//my header//---------------------

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#ifndef STACK_H_
#define STACK_H_

template<class T> 
class StackTest
{

private:
unsigned int maxSize;
T *stackData;
int top;

public:
StackTest(int size){
    stackData = new T[size];//to hold the T ‌type data items 
    top = -1;//no items on the stack
    maxSize = size;//set maximum size that stack can hold
}

virtual ~StackTest(){}

int count(){
    return top + 1;
}

bool isEmpty(){
    return top == -1 ? true : false;
}

bool isFull(){
    return top == maxSize - 1 ? true : false;
}

T* peek(){
    if(!isEmpty())//check for empty
        return &stackData[top - 1];
}

T* pop(){
    if(!isEmpty()){
        top -= 1;//decrease the top by 1 to indicate the delete
        return &stackData[top];//return deleted item
    }
    return NULL;
}

void push(T* item){
    stackData[top++] = *item;//insert to data array and increase the top by one 
}
};


#endif /* STACK_H_ */

-----------//my main//---------------

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Pair.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

int dataTest;
string strTest;
StackTest<int> intStack(10);
StackTest<string> stringStack(50);

//Insert data into the stack
dataTest = 3;
intStack.push(&dataTest);
dataTest = 4;
intStack.push(&dataTest);
dataTest = 5;
intStack.push(&dataTest);
dataTest = 6;
intStack.push(&dataTest);
strTest = "test";
stringStack.push(&strTest);

//Show the top item
cout << *intStack.peek() << endl;
cout << *stringStack.peek() << endl;

//Pull the top item out (twice)
intStack.pop();
intStack.pop();

//Show the new top item
cout << *intStack.peek() << endl;

return 0;
}
```

So if anyone feels like giving me some pointers I would really appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't include C headers like `#include <stdlib.h>`; if necessary, rather use the C++ versions like `#include <cstdlib>`. I don't see why this header is currently necessary in your program, though. You could replace `unsigned int maxSize;` with `std::size_t maxSize;` though and would require it.

Comment: `x == y ? true : false` is equivalent to simple `x == y`.

Comment: @Elazar: Bonus question -- under what conditions is `x == (y ? true: false)` the same as well?

Comment: If it keeps crashing on you there must be some error messages, you may just not see it. You just have to find. Make sure you run debug version of the program. There must be some exception thrown or something. Get the errors message and it'll help you (and us too to point out the error).

Comment: @BenVoigt if `y` is boolean then `(y ? true : false)` is equivalent to `y`, and hence `x == (y ? true: false)` is equivalent to `x == y`.

Comment: @Elazar: That's what I came up with as well.

Comment: Ok, I ran it in debug mode and this is the error that comes up: Unhandled exception at 0x0FEB1190 (msvcr110d.dll) in TemplateClassTest1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000. I am guessing that it has something to do with memory allocation

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your implementation. One of the most subtle is in the `push()` member function:

```
void push(T* item){
    stackData[top++] = *item; //insert to data array and increase the top by one
    //           ^^
    //           You want pre-increment here!
}
```

This is incrementing `top` and using the *old* value as an index into `stackData`. Since `top` is `-1` when the stack is empty, your program is actually doing:

```
stackData[-1] = *item;
top = 0;
```

Needless to say that the first assignment results in undefined behavior.

Another source of undefined behavior is the `peek()` member function, which does not return anything when the stack is empty:

```
T* peek(){
    if(!isEmpty())//check for empty
        return &stackData[top - 1];
}
```

Per paragraph 6.6.3/2 of the C++11 Standard:

> [...] Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined
>   behavior in a value-returning function.

But that's not the only issue: the other problem is with the access of `stackData`:

```
return &stackData[top - 1];
```

When `top` is not equal to or greater than one, this will also result in undefined behavior, since you would be taking the address of a (non-)object located at a negative address in the array.

Also, I suggest to rewrite `isEmpty()` and `isFull()` as follows:

```
bool isEmpty(){
    return (top == -1);
}

bool isFull(){
   return (top == maxSize - 1);
}
```

As a general advice, consider not using the value `-1` for `top` when the stack is empty.  [As Ben Voigt mentions in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16532712/template-stack-and-lifo-c/16532764#comment23742820_16532764), this is leading you to a lot of off-by-one errors.

Also, [as pointed out by DyP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16532712/template-stack-and-lifo-c/16532764?noredirect=1#comment23743034_16532764), your destructor is not freeing the memory allocated in the constructor, so your `StackTest` object is leaking memory. And after doing that, since we're at it, you may want to have a look at the so-called [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three), that your program would be violating.

Comment: There are a lot of off-by-one errors created by the choice of `-1` instead of `0` for an empty stack.

Comment: @BenVoigt Or, to put it differently, most of the issues boil down to a wrong use of `top` (want to use `top+1`) outside the `ctor` and `isEmpty`

Comment: @DyP: No, I think it is `top + 0` that is desired.

Comment: @BenVoigt If you don't want to use another `bool` to indicate that the stack is empty, you can use the OP's approach. The ctor, `count`, `isEmpty` and `isFull` all are working with `top == -1` for an empty stack - that's half of the functions. It's error prone though, as we can see here :)

Comment: There's still a memory leak as the dtor doesn't deallocate `stackData` ;)