# Confused about deleting pointers in stack

Tags: c++

I'm trying to free up memory whenever possible, but I keep triggering breakpoints when calling delete. It's been awhile since I've done c++ so I don't remember the exact way to do this.

main.cpp

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    LIFO lifo = *new LIFO();

    LIFO::Element element1  = *new LIFO::Element(1);
    LIFO::Element element2  = *new LIFO::Element(2);
    LIFO::Element element3  = *new LIFO::Element(3);
    LIFO::Element element4  = *new LIFO::Element(4);
    LIFO::Element element5  = *new LIFO::Element(5);
    LIFO::Element element6  = *new LIFO::Element(6);

    lifo.Push(element1);
    lifo.Push(element2);
    lifo.Push(element3);
    lifo.Push(element4);
    lifo.Push(element5);
    lifo.Push(element6);

    lifo.Peek(lifo.mSize);

    lifo.Pop();
    lifo.Pop();
    lifo.Pop();

    lifo.Peek(lifo.mSize);

    lifo.Push(element1);
    lifo.Push(element2);
    lifo.Push(element3);
    lifo.Push(element4);
    lifo.Push(element5);
    lifo.Push(element6);

    lifo.Peek(lifo.mSize);

    lifo.Empty();

    lifo.Peek(lifo.mSize);

    return 0;
}
```

LIFO.h

```
class LIFO
{
public:

    unsigned int mSize;

    LIFO(void)
        :mSize(0)
    {
        mTop = nullptr;
    }


    ~LIFO(void)
    {

    }

    class Element
    {
    public:
        Element* mNextElement;
        int mData;

        Element()
            :mData(0)
            ,mNextElement(nullptr)
        {

        }

        Element(int data)
            :mData(data)
            ,mNextElement(nullptr)
        {

        }

        ~Element()
        {

        }

    };

    Element* mTop;

    void Push(Element& element)
    {
        if(mTop != nullptr)
        {
            Element* newElement = &element;
            newElement->mNextElement = mTop;
            mTop = newElement;

            delete newElement;
            newElement = nullptr;
        }
        else
        {
            mTop = &element;
        }

        ++mSize;
    }

    void Pop()
    {
        if(mTop != nullptr)
        {
            Element* oldElement = mTop;
            mTop = mTop->mNextElement;
            --mSize;

            delete oldElement;
            oldElement = nullptr;
        }
    }

    void Empty()
    {
        while(mTop != nullptr)
        {
            Pop();
        }
    }

    void Peek(unsigned int depth)
    {
        Element* current = mTop;

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < depth; ++i)
        {
            if(current != nullptr)
            {
                std::cout << current->mData << '\n';

                if(current->mNextElement != nullptr)
                {
                    current = current->mNextElement;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        delete current;
        current = nullptr;
    }

};
```

I also tried these in the destructors at one point and they didn't work right either

```
~LIFO(void)
{
    Element* current = mTop;

    while(current != nullptr)
    {
        Element* next = current->mNextElement;
        delete current;
        current = next;
    }

    current = nullptr;
}
```

How do I safely free up memory in this stack?

Comment: `void Push(Element& element)` why don't you take Element as pointer instead ?

Comment: You may get Your Solution from here..
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16532712/template-stack-and-lifo-c)

Comment: Lines like `LIFO lifo = *new LIFO();` clearly indicate that you need to go back to the basics. Working through the examples in a text book or a site like http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/ would be good for your C++ skills.

Comment: "I keep triggering breakpoints when calling delete." I think "breakpoint" is now what you mean here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of `Peek` is wrong. Peek doesn't delete any elements in the stack. Remove the delete statement in Peek. The interface is still wrong though.

Coming to Push, try this modified Push.

```
void Push(Element* element)
{
    if(mTop != nullptr)
    {
        Element* currTop = mTop;            
        element->mNextElement = currTop;
        mTop = element;            
    }
    else
    {
        mTop = element;
    }
    ++mSize;
}
```

Now the usage of your class should be

```
LIFO* lifo = new LIFO();
LIFO::Element* element1  = new LIFO::Element(1);
```

Your code in the destructor `~Lifo()` is fine. After you're done with your stack operations, delete the lifo using the statement `delete lifo;`.

Comment: A suggestion is, don't use raw pointers to own the memory use smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr` even if it meant for learning purpose.